# eval an input string on button press in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, eval, onchange

I want to create a web-app coding game with react that involves evaluating some user (javascript) input.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange(key) {
    return event => this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value });
  }

  funScript() {
    eval(this.state.code);
  }

  anotherScript() {
    console.log("Will this work?");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type={"text"}
          value={this.state.code}
          onChange={this.handleChange('code')}
         />
        <button onClick={this.funScript()} >run</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I was hoping that the text input would be able to evaluate javascript on button press by the user (the user types in this.anotherScript(); and the console logs "Will this work?". Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I suspect its an issue specific to React. As soon as the input box is typed in, it tries to evaluate the string (without the button even being pressed!). See here for an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/54rkp584ll

Anyone have a proper React solution that doesn't break javascript on the first character input (and evaluates the function)?

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
<button onClick={this.funScript()} >run</button>
```

You are calling `this.funScript`. Remove the parens and you'll just pass the function like you want. Also, `funScript` needs to be bound to this for it to work.

Comment: Hmm.. I found just passing a function that executes this.funScript() inside works without bounding funScript. https://codesandbox.io/s/54rkp584ll


`<button onClick={() => {this.funScript()}} >run</button>`

removing the parentheses didn't work, but I'm guessing because I didn't bound this.funScript

Comment: Yeah, creating an arrow function that calls the function is basically binding the function. If you're not familiar with arrow functions and `this`, you should check it out. It's not super obvious but very helpful/important to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have `funScript`, which evaluates your code with proper context:

```
class Test {

    // ...

    funScript() {
        const code = ("" + this.state.code).replace(/this/ig, "__self__");
        const execute = new Function("__self__", code);
        execute(this);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is this making the "this." unnecessary in the executed string of code? Useful, but I'm not sure it addressed the issue. Also, I'm not familiar with the new Function syntax, but I'll look into it

Comment: To evaluate method from the component `Test`, you have to `pass` a context manually. If it's not necessary, you can skip the code with this/self. The good point in this code is that you can redefine window, document and other global objects, which can be a huge security improvement.

Comment: I'm not as concerned with Security (since its front-end, which shouldn't contain the secure info for my purpose, except perhaps the session token...) as I am with sandboxing the code so I can interrupt the execution of user-written code which causes errors and infinite loops, etc... but this seems like it could possibly help with the sandboxing?